# How to get the value from a kendo Editor in my model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, editor, kendo-ui

I am trying to use a Kendo UI Editor control in my ASP.NET MVC application. No success until now, since I cannot manage to get the value in the editor back to the model in the controller.

My model is very simple (to edit an html page in my website):

```
public class EditedPage
{
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Title { get; set; }

[AllowHtml]
public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

And my view includes this code:

```
@model Page

<h2>@Model.Title</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Name)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Title)

    @(Html.Kendo().EditorFor(m => m.Content)
    .Name("Editor")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:800px;height:600px;margin-left:20px;" })
    )

    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="@Resources.StringResources.Save" class="k-button"/>
    </div>
}
```

I was expecting the post method in the controller to get the model filled. If I add simple editors for Name and Title (in the sample code they are hidden) it works fine, but Content always comes back as null.

Here is my controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditPage(Page page)
{
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
 return View(page);

//save content in a file

return View("CustomPages");
}
```

What am I missing? I guess that I need some javascript to get the value from the editor, but I don't know how to achieve it.

Any help would be welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Name your editor 'Content'.  Really.  :)

#### EDIT

```
@model Page

<h2>@Model.Title</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Name)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Title)

    @(Html.Kendo().EditorFor(m => m.Content)
    .Name("Content")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:800px;height:600px;margin-left:20px;" })
    )

    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="@Resources.StringResources.Save" class="k-button"/>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Constructive feedback is ok, but you may as well explain yourself. That ain't helpful at all.

Comment: IT worked. Now it seems I have to encode the returned HTML. Why caused the name the problem?

Comment: It is just a Kendo quirk, the Name is which field in your model that gets assigned the value deep in the depth of how Kendo works.  Since you are using the EditorFor you may be able to not even use the .Name and then the precedence should fall to the specified field - I think.  I always explicitly name though just to be sure.

Comment: Removing .Name() worked for me. Naming the editor "Content" did not.

Comment: I have not experienced this problem on more recent releases, not sure which it changed - over a year maybe.  Now, if you use EditorFor, like Joe mentions just don't also use .Name().

Comment: Welcome to kendo's retardation ... everything has to be "just so"

Comment: It's just how the model binder works. By specifying name, you give the input a name attribute, which is then matched by the model binder and it knows how to bind it to that property. It's not "retarded".

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and the only way I could get this resolved when using and EditorFor was to not populate the Name property at all.