# ASP.NET MVC 4 exchange (bind) model between a controller and a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I'm trying to share instance of a type called 'Version' between the Controller and the View.

It works well from the controller to the view. but on the way back, I get the instance as it was sent to the view without the changes in the form.

The view:

```
 @model Models.Pages.Versions

 @using (Html.BeginForm(Model)) 
{ 


     ViewBag.Title = "Create";



 <div>
     Title:&nbsp;
     @Html.TextBox("titleTb",Model.Title)  </div> 

 @(Html.Kendo().Editor()
     .Name("editor")
     .Value(Model.Content)
     .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 740px;height:440px" })
     .ImageBrowser(imageBrowser => imageBrowser
     .Image("~/Content/UserFiles/Images/{0}")    
     .Read("Read", "ImageBrowser")
     .Create("Create", "ImageBrowser")
     .Destroy("Destroy", "ImageBrowser")
     .Upload("Upload", "ImageBrowser")
     .Thumbnail("Thumbnail", "ImageBrowser")) )

 <br />


     <input type="submit" value="Create" /> }
```

The controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View(new Models.Pages.Versions() { Title = "New Title", Content = "Test"});
        }

 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Models.Pages.Versions version)
        {
            ViewBag.Title = version.Content;

            Models.Pages.Registry createdPage = Models.Pages.Registry.InsertNew(Models.Ref.connectionString);
            version.PageId = createdPage.Id;
            version.Author = User.Identity.Name;
            version.TimeStamp = DateTime.Now;
            version.Insert();

            return View(createdPage.Id);
        }
```

**Update**
Looking at the querystring when submitting the form, it appears that the input in the form has no affect over it at all.

Comment: Is the data actually saved to the DB ?

Comment: There is no problem with saving nor retrieving the data from the DB. the problem is that i cannot see the changes that were made to the model by the view.

Comment: @haim770 it is exactly what happens. can you please post that as an answer as well as a small tip where I should start looking (any errors log or something)?

Thanks.

Comment: Show your `Versions` class.

Comment: Did you try using Kendo().EditorFor(m=> m.Content).Name("Content")

Comment: Actually, when you POST the data, did you debug and check the value of your `version`?

Comment: @haim770 yes I have and it is the same as originally sent to the view. it appears that the changes in the form are not carried to the query string. I've updated my question.

Comment: "QueryString"? It's a `POST`, right?

Comment: @Nilesh it appears that when I apply this for with the lambda it works on the title textbox. will you post it as an answer please?

Comment: So are you getting expected model in the Action? I dont have access to VS or any tools so I could not try this out and post the answer.

Comment: yeah, I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14405264/how-to-get-the-value-from-a-kendo-editor-in-my-model

and it suggests just about you suggested, and works.